# InfoPath Secondary WCF Data Source's XML Structure

Tags: xml, web-services, wcf, infopath-2007

I'm developing a WCF Service to be consumed by InfoPath 2007 forms. After adding the Service as a secondary Datasource, InfoPath itself will autogenerate a certain Structure. for example:

[image: Secondary data source structure in infopath]

my Problem with this are the generated xpaths. displayname's xpath for example:

```
/dfs:myFields/dfs:dataFields/ns3:whoamiResponse/ns3:whoamiResult/q1:displayname
```

Since my Webservice has to replace an older one which is implemented in many forms with logic refferencing exactly a certain xpath i have to get the exact same xpath generated in my new Webservice.

How can i influence these generated prefixes like **ns3**:whoamiResult/**q1**:displayname ?

I noticed that **q1** appeared after i changed the return type of my Operation from DataSet to a custom Class. And tns/ns1/ns2/**ns3** .. is depending on Namespaces i changed in the [ServiceContract], [ServiceBehaviour] and some other Attributes.

```
[ServiceContract(Name="Webservice", Namespace = "BestNamespaceToBeEnteredHere")]
public interface IWebservice
{

    [OperationContract]
    //...
}
```

Could someone point me into the right direction? Can i somehow pass a cusstom Schema with the Webservice Response where i can define how the structure should look like?

cheers! phil

Answer (score 1):

The `Namespace` property on your `ServiceContract` and `DataContract`s effect the namespaces used in the SOAP response.  The prefixes are typically arbitrary, and I think it is rather queer that InfoPath displays them, but there are a great many articles on how to influence them.

While I don't typically support link only answers, I list them below as I could not explain it as well as they already have:

- [Changing prefixes in XML responses for WCF services](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2010/06/13/changing-prefixes-in-xml-responses.aspx)
- [Customize WCF Envelope and Namespace Prefix](http://vanacosmin.ro/Articles/Read/WCFEnvelopeNamespacePrefix)

Duplicates:

- [Customize SOAP Header namespace prefixes in WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21495857/customize-soap-header-namespace-prefixes-in-wcf)
- [Change namespace Prefix WCF Envelope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506713/change-namespace-prefix-wcf-envelope)